# inverse Fourier transforms of $\dfrac{f(\omega)}{j\omega}$

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm having a problem with the inverse Fourier transform (IFT) of $\dfrac{g(\omega)}{j\omega}$, where $j=\sqrt{-1}$, and $\omega$ is the angular frequency.

It seems that the IFT is convolution of $g(t)$ and $0.5\operatorname{sign}(t)$, but the answer looks dependent on the value $g(0)$.

for example, if $g(\omega)\sim C\omega$ where $w\sim 0$ ($C$ is constant), my answer looks correct.

but if $g(\omega)=C$ where $w\sim 0$, some consideration of adding delta function seems to be needed.

Really thank you for answer.

Comment: +1. Working with $t \geq 0$ systems with Fourier transforms is often overlooked. Keep exploring!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, in my task the function $g(t)$ turns on $t>=0$, but $g(\omega=0)$ is dependent on prior calculation. you mean after the iFT, a suitable constant which makes the iFT turns on $t>=0$ must be added ?